# Windows App can't use Grid MemberFunction

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, store

Ihave some Problems to attach Textblocks in my Grid.
I cant use `SetRow(Frameworkelement,index)`;

The ErrorMessage is something like that I cant access the MemberFunction with an instance reference.
Instead i should use a TypeName, but how?

```
 private FrameworkElement CreateGrid(int i)
        {
            double w = 775;
            double l = 1105;

            TextBlock header = CreateHeader("someRndStuffHeader");
            RowDefinition headerRowDefinition = new RowDefinition
            {
                MinHeight = header.ActualHeight,
                MaxHeight = header.ActualHeight,  
            };

            TextBlock footer = CreateFooter("someRndStuffFooter");
            RowDefinition footerRowDefinition = new RowDefinition
            {
                MinHeight = footer.ActualHeight,
                MaxHeight = footer.ActualHeight

            };

            double contentHeight = l- header.ActualHeight - footer.ActualHeight;
            RowDefinition contentRowDefinition = new RowDefinition
            {
                MinHeight = contentHeight,
                MaxHeight = contentHeight,
            };

            ColumnDefinition gridColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                MaxWidth = w,
                MinWidth = w,
            };

            Grid page = new Grid();
            string name = "printPage" + i.ToString();
            page.Name = name;

            page.RowDefinitions.Add(headerRowDefinition);
            page.RowDefinitions.Add(contentRowDefinition);
            page.RowDefinitions.Add(footerRowDefinition);
            page.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColumnDefinition);

            // I CANT USE THIS 
            page.SetRow(header, 1);

            return page;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetRow(FrameworkElement framework,int value) is a static method. Instance members cannot use it.
Use like this :-

```
      Grid.SetRow(header,1);
```

However, before you can achieve that, you have to make header and footer TextBlocks children of the newly formed grid because SetRow method sets the row of framework element only when it is a child of any grid.

So you will have to add these two statements :-

```
  page.Children.Add(header);
  page.Children.Add(footer);
```

Further, here the new grid i.e page, it has to be also assigned a parent grid. When you create a new AppPage (BlankPage.xaml) then by default a parent grid is already rendered by the system. Name this parent grid as say x:Name="Layout" and then add grid 'page' to this 'Layout' grid. I am giving here full code, both xaml and .cs. I have created a button and then when i press the button, new grid is created

In XAMl :-

```
<Grid x:Name="layout" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="587,475,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

In .cs :-

```
    private FrameworkElement CreateGrid(int i)
    {
        double w = 775;
        double l = 1105;

        TextBlock header = CreateHeader("someRndStuffHeader");
        RowDefinition headerRowDefinition = new RowDefinition
        {
            MinHeight = header.ActualHeight,
            MaxHeight = header.ActualHeight,
        };

        TextBlock footer = CreateFooter("someRndStuffFooter");
        RowDefinition footerRowDefinition = new RowDefinition
        {
            MinHeight = footer.ActualHeight,
            MaxHeight = footer.ActualHeight

        };

        double contentHeight = l - header.ActualHeight - footer.ActualHeight;
        RowDefinition contentRowDefinition = new RowDefinition
        {
            MinHeight = contentHeight,
            MaxHeight = contentHeight,
        };

        ColumnDefinition gridColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition()
        {
            MaxWidth = w,
            MinWidth = w,
        };

        Grid page = new Grid();
        string name = "printPage" + i.ToString();
        page.Name = name;

        page.RowDefinitions.Add(headerRowDefinition);
        page.RowDefinitions.Add(contentRowDefinition);
        page.RowDefinitions.Add(footerRowDefinition);
        page.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColumnDefinition);


        **Grid.SetRow(header, 1);
        page.Children.Add(header);
        page.Children.Add(footer);**

        return page;
    }

    private TextBlock CreateFooter(string p)
    {
        return new TextBlock() { Width=300,Height=300,Text=p};
    }

    private TextBlock CreateHeader(string p)
    {
        return new TextBlock() { Width = 300, Height = 300, Text = p };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        layout.Children.Add(CreateGrid(1));
    }
```